# Display:table layout undesired padding behavior

Tags: html, css

Given this basic 3 columns layout,

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.center {
  padding-top: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">uno</div>
  <div class="center">dos</div>
  <div class="right">tres</div>
</div>
```

When adding padding-top to the .center div, the others also display it. How do I add a padding-top to the center div alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy: Try to do the following:

```
 .wrapper {
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
 }      

 .wrapper>div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;  // Add this line :)
 }

 .center {
    padding-top: 3em;
 }
```

When you use display: **table-cell** in a div, the div will align vertically to the center... so by doing **vertical-align:top** you will force all the divs align vertically to the top and then the center div will assume the padding as you desire.

Comment: I´m glad it´s working now!! :) So do not forget to mark my aswer as the right answer! ;)